# No value given from one or more parameters when pressing delete button

Tags: c#

Current one i'm doing is after choosing a data from MsDatabase and after        string

```
query = "delete from RegisterItem where  Name =" +txtName1.Text+"";
```

it shows a error saying No value given from one or more parameters , While i've check that the txtName1 Matches the column in Name

```
{
    OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();

    public MenClothing(string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtUsername.Text = text;
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Teronkee\Desktop\OFFICAL STAC\StacProductions\DatabaseSaveItem.accdb";
    }

    public MenClothing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Teronkee\Desktop\OFFICAL STAC\StacProductions\DatabaseSaveItem.accdb";


    }


    private int upperCase(string pass)
    {
        int num = 0;
        foreach (char ch in pass)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(ch))
            {
                num++;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }

    private void btnlogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 Return = new Form2(txtUsername.Text);
        Return.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void MenClothing_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            string query = "select * from RegisterItem";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
            }

            connect.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }

        connect.Close();
    }
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ItemUrl.Text;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ItemUrl.Text;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try { 
        connect.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = "insert into RegisterItem([Name], [Url],[Description], [Price]) values('" + ItemName.Text + "','" + ItemUrl.Text + "','" + ItemDescription.Text + "','" + ItemPrice.Text + "')";

            string str = ItemUrl.Text;
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = str;
            string str1 = textBox1.Text;
            Image img = Image.FromFile(str);
            pictureBox1.Image = img;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");

            txtID1.Text = txtUsername.Text;
                txtName1.Text = ItemName.Text;
                txtDescription1.Text = ItemDescription.Text;
               txtPrice1.Text = ItemPrice.Text;

               ItemName.Text = "";
              ItemDescription.Text = "";
                ItemPrice.Text = "";

            connect.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {
        MessageBox.Show("Error " +ex);

        }

        connect.Close();

    }

    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            string query = "delete from RegisterItem where  Name ="                    +txtName1.Text+"";
            command.CommandText = query;


            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data deleted ");

            connect.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);

        }
        connect.Close();

        //if (txtUsername.Text == txtID1.Text)
        //   { 
        //   txtName1.Text = "";
        //    txtDescription1.Text = "";
        //    txtPrice1.Text = "";
        //  }
    }
    private void ItemDescription_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void AddString_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string namestr = txtName1.Text;
        comboBox1.Items.Add(namestr);
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { 
            connect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            string query = "select * from RegisterItem where Name='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {


                txtName1.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
                txtDescription1.Text = reader["Description"].ToString();
                txtPrice1.Text = reader["Price"].ToString();
            }

            connect.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }

        connect.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It works when i exchange the Name(Second row) Into ID ( First row ) , but not with the name which i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not quoted correctly.
ID is a number so it doesn't require single quotes, Name is a string - it does.

thats why ID works and name does not.
change your delete query to

```
    string query = "delete from RegisterItem where  Name = '" + txtName1.Text + "'";
```

you should use string.format() to avoid these mistakes, better yet use [paramaterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for addressing this for me , Another error i encountered was Error System.NotSupportedException : The given path's format is not supported .  After clicking on button1 , Is it because of the codes i used to convert the url into image? Did i put it in the wrong spot inside button1? @Stavm

Comment: @TeaCake That error usually means a path to a file is not valid - I have no idea what value is in ItemUrl, but it's probably where you want to be looking at, depending on which line you get the exception.

by the way I believe your question was answered, so marking this question as 'resolved' using the V to the left of the answer would be considered the appropriate act.

if you have any more questions feel free to open up a new question